# conveting bytes to image using tinytag and PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using tinytags module in python to get the cover art of a mp3 file and want to display or store it. The return type of the variable is showing to be bytes. I have tried fumbling around with PIL using frombytes but to no avail. Is there any method to convert the bytes to image?

```
from tinytag import TinyTag
tag = TinyTag.get("03. Me, Myself & I.mp3", image=True)

img = tag.get_image()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got a PNG image when I called `tag.get_image()` but I guess you might get a JPEG. Either way, you can wrap it in a `BytesIO` and open it with **PIL/Pillow** or display it.  Carrying on from your code:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

...
im = tag.get_image()

# Make a PIL Image
pi = Image.open(io.BytesIO(im))

# Save as PNG, or JPEG
pi.save('cover.png')

# Display
pi.show()
```

Note that you don't *have* to use **PIL/Pillow**. You could look at the first few bytes and if they are a PNG signature (\x89PNG) save data as binary with PNG extension. If the signature is JPEG (\xff \xd8) save data as binary with JPEG extension.