# Python pillow: read image content from a list of byte chunks and save to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am coming into a scenario that I need to use python pillow to read image from a given list of byte chunks (e.g., an iterator with type `Iterator[bytes]`), then save it to a location.

I hope I could come up with a method like this:

```py
def save_image(chunks: Iterator[bytes]):
    pil_image: Image = Image.open(chunks)  # Here is where I am getting blocked
    # ... some image operations
    pil_image.save(SOME_PATH, format=pil_image.format)
```

But it seems that I didn't find any documents or other questions that can resolve my question, to allow python pillow to read images from a list of byte chunks. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to accumulate the chunks into a `BytesIO` and pass the accumulated buffer as the sole parameter to `Image.open()`.

Same concept as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64581557/2836621).

Untested, but it will presumably look something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

buf = BytesIO()
for chunk in chunks:
   buf.write(chunk)

im = Image.open(buf)
```

---

If you are dealing with extremely large or numerous chunks, you might want to accumulate on disk rather than in memory:

```
with open('image.bin', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in chunks:
       fd.write(chunk)

im = Image.open('image.bin')
```

Comment: Works for me, really appreciate it! BTW, is there any other way to do this if the byte chunk is really huge (for example, a 400MB huge image comes with an iterator of 400 chunks with 1MB each from a sender), it could be a bad idea to dump everything into memory. Does pillow have the ability to save the image with such "segments"?

Comment: I added a section to cover that at the end of my answer.